# scale_x_bd - how to get date formatting correct

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to display `d-m-y h` on the x-axis using `scale_x_bd`. However, I seem to not be able to get the `scales::date_format` function to work properly

What I have tried so far:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(bdscale)


s1_date <- dmy_hms("30/09/2019 00:00:00")
s2_date <- dmy_hms("08/10/2019 00:00:00")


df <- data.frame(date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz="UTC"),
                     to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 23:00", tz="UTC"),
                     by="hour"),
                 value = sample(1:75, 72)) 

p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") 


#does not work
p1 + scale_x_bd(business.dates = df %>% pull(date) %>% 
                  unique %>% sort, 
                labels = scales::date_format(format = "%d-%m-%y %H", tz = "UTC"),
                max.major.breaks = 75) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Separately, could someone also provide a link to resource that has all kinds of imaginable date formats!

Comment: Correct format on x-axis would be: `01-01-2012 00` etc

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `bdscale` only handles Date class dates, which are numeric values in days elapsed since an origin date, while POSIXct class dates are numeric values in seconds elapsed since an origin date. See [this issue](https://github.com/dvmlls/bdscale/issues/6) on the `bdscale` github page, for example (it includes some suggestions for how to create a transformation that works for POSIXct dates).

Note what the plot looks like when we change the year format to `%Y`, which prints the full year value:

```
p1 + scale_x_bd(business.dates = df$date, 
                labels = scales::date_format(format = "%d-%m-%Y %H", tz = "UTC"),
                max.major.breaks=75) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Note the enormous year values. This suggests that one of the functions in bdscale is probably converting the POSIXct date to numeric and then converting the numeric value (which is in seconds elapsed) to Date class as if it were in days elapsed. You can see this with the following code:

```
# Correct result
scales::date_format("%d-%m-%Y %H")(df$date)

[1] "01-01-2012 00" "01-01-2012 01" "01-01-2012 02" "01-01-2012 03" ...

# What bdscale is effectively doing
as.Date(as.numeric(df$date))

[1] "3630726-03-29" "3630736-02-05" "3630745-12-14" "3630755-10-23" ...
```

If you look at the code for the bdscale functions, you can see that this is what is happening:

```
getAnywhere(bd_trans)
getAnywhere(bd2t)
getAnywhere(t2bd)
```

> ```
> > getAnywhere(bd_trans)
> function (business.dates, breaks = bd_breaks(business.dates)) {
>     transform <- function(dates) bd2t(dates, business.dates)
>     inverse <- function(ts) t2bd(ts, business.dates)
>     trans_new("date", transform = transform, inverse = inverse, 
>         breaks = breaks, domain = range(business.dates))
> }
>
> > getAnywhere(bd2t)
> function (dates, business.dates) {
>     result = match(dates, business.dates) - 1
>     structure(as.numeric(result), names = names(dates))
> }
>
> > getAnywhere(t2bd)
> function (ts, business.dates) {
>     result = business.dates[pmin(pmax(round(ts, 0), 0) + 1, length(business.dates))]
>     structure(result, class = "Date")
> }
> ```

Comment: This kind of detailed, in-depth answer is what makes this platform rich and productive. Tks!