# how to get x-axis text to read `d-m-y h`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a plot with `d-m-y h` as my x-axis text. 
I have tried and faield using `bdscale` (see prior post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193452/scale-x-bd-how-to-get-date-formatting-correct))

Ideally, I would like to use `ggplot2` to achieve this, however, I am open to other possibilities to getting this done.

This is my sample code:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(bdscale)


s1_date <- dmy_hms("30/09/2019 00:00:00")
s2_date <- dmy_hms("08/10/2019 00:00:00")


df <- data.frame(date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("2012-1-1 0:00", tz="UTC"),
                            to=as.POSIXct("2012-1-3 23:00", tz="UTC"),
                            by="hour"),
                 value = sample(1:75, 72)) 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

All I want is for the `x-axis` text to read `01-01-2012 00` etc

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a specific axis function that allows you to do this.  I've modified your code to include it.

```
df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
    geom_col() +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "6 hours",
                     date_labels = "%m/%d/%y %H") +
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```